# arules package - preparing data

Tags: r, math, machine-learning

How do i prepare the data in the form of "transactions" but for each transaction ID, the temporal effect/sequence is being taken into account? I found that using "split" function, they will be order in alphabetical order.

eg:

```
ID Items Sequence
1  D     1
1  A     2
1  C     3
2  A     1 
2  B     2
```

Desired output in transactions:

```
ID Items
1  D A C #notice that A comes after D as it is dictacted by sequence variable 
        #                                                        here for the order
2  A B
```

Regards.

Comment: Am I missing something or have you forgotten to also add C to the desired output?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Edited.

Comment: Shouldn't last row of input `data` be `2 B 2` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Using lapply and rbind,

```
DF = read.table(text="ID Items Sequence
1  D     1
1  A     2
1  C     3
2  A     1 
2  B     2",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,na.strings="")


DF
#  ID Items Sequence
#1  1     D        1
#2  1     A        2
#3  1     C        3
#4  2     A        1
#5  2     B        2
```

For each ID, subset the dataframe, sort by Sequence,combine the Items and return ouput for each ID

```
DF_new = do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(DF$ID),function(x) {

subset_DF = DF[DF$ID==x,];
subset_DF = subset_DF[,order(subset_DF$Sequence)]
subset_DF = subset_DF[,c("ID","Items")]
subset_DF$Items = paste0(subset_DF$Items,collapse=" ")
subset_DF = unique(subset_DF)
rownames(subset_DF)= NULL
return(subset_DF)
}))

DF_new
#  ID Items
#1  1 D A C
#2  2   A B
```

Comment: Run into the error as such:
Error in subset_DF[, c("ID", "Items")] : incorrect number of dimensions
Called from: FUN(X[[i]], ...)

when the list is longer, ie.: more ID or items

Comment: could you update the your post with output `dput(head(data,5))`, where data is your input dataframe

Comment: to avoid confusion, will leave my output here as I have slightly changed the data by extending more rows with random inputs:


    Output from dput(head(DF,5)):
    structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Items = c("D", "A", 
    "C", "A", "B"), Sequence = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("ID", 
    "Items", "Sequence"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: the function runs fine for me with the `data` you posted, can you confirm it does for you as well